# How to update map marker in angular application

Tags: angularjs

So i have created this small map application **[HERE](http://purplefront.net/a-map/)**, and as you can see it shows your current localtion, now the problem is the marker will not show on the current location, If you `CTRL+U` you will see that the code for the marker is:

```
<openlayers ol-center="center"  height="400px">
            <ol-marker lat="center.lat" lon="center.lon" message="Your current location." ng-model="center" >
            </ol-marker>
</openlayers>
```

The `lat="center.lat"` and `lon="center.lon"` in the beginning is `0` , now if i hardcode the values of `lat` and `lon` to my current location , ofcourse the marker will show in my current location, but how do i update the values dynamically ?

I am using `angular.js` , `openLayers3` and **[openlayers-angular-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive)** , So to repeat my question, how do i update the marker dynamically ?

Comment: the key i beleive is to change the `var getMarkerDefaults = function() { return { projection: 'EPSG:4326', lat: 0, lon: 0, coord: [], show: true, showOnMouseOver: false, showOnMouseClick: false, keepOneOverlayVisible: false }; };` lat and lon in the source of angular-openlayers-directive.js on line 634 , source here purplefront.net/a-map/js/angular-openlayers-directive.js

Answer (score 3):

All you need is to add "autodiscover : true" to your center object in your controller.

As it is explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive/blob/master/doc/02-center-attribute.md) of the directive.

Also, you need to put the value bound in the marker:

```
<openlayers ol-center="center"  height="400px">
        <ol-marker lat="{{center.lat}}" lon="{{center.lon}}" message="Your current location." ng-model="center" >
        </ol-marker>
```

Comment: Its discovering the location correctly , just not adding the marker to the location ! , i have already set `"autodiscover : true" `, that part works fine

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer, marker needs to get the values from the scope, so you need to tell it with {{}}.

Comment: I really taught your solution would work , it did't though :( :/,  i found the solution though , its here http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/063-markers-properties-example.html , needed to use the `ol-marker-properties="center"` attribute :) +1 though

Answer (score 2):

Use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`. Angular doesn't know you are modifying the scope inside `setTimeout` so it doesn't update the view.

`$timeout` uses `setTimeout()` internally but also calls `$apply()` to have angular run a digest.

rememeber to also inject it in controller

Comment: I will try that , the setTimeout was just for testing , i doubt the solution would work , see how the marker HTML is modified in the inspect element part , see here http://purplefront.net/a-map/

Comment: I didn't dig into the code on that link but it did at least zoom to my location

Comment: yes but the marker want adjust itself to your current location !

Comment: I'm not familar with that open layers module. I have had good luck using angular-google maps and angular leaflet though

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
<ol-marker ol-marker-properties="center" ></ol-marker>

angular.extend($scope, {
            center: {
                lat: 0,
                lon: 0,
                autodiscover: true
                label: {
                    message: 'Your current location.',
                    show: true,
                    showOnMouseOver: true
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you share a fiddle or plunker ?

Answer (score 1):

good example with code to work with map in angular JS

> http://ngmap.github.io/drawings.html